# Instagram get someone's posts just With instagram's username

Tags: node.js, express, backend, instagram, instagram-api

I want make a NodeJS application that use Instagram API but I couldn't find API that get someone's Instagram post with just his or her username not access Token please help me.

Comment: There is no official API that supports this use case.

Comment: @AndrewL is any way that i can get my data the way that i find myself is only give 12post please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could find my solvation in this library [instagram-web-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-web-api).

```html
const InstagramWeb = require("instagram-web-api");
const { password, username } = require("../../config/Instagram");

const client = new InstagramWeb({
  username: username,
  password: password,
});
if (password && username) {
  client.login();
}
```